# PHP com HTML - Colocar um array dentro de um select html

Tags: php, html, array

Olá, sou iniciante e estou com a seguinte dúvida, tenho um array, onde um dos parâmetros vem do banco, ali onde está o número 5, vem do banco.

```
$inicio = 1;
$ultimo = 5; //esse valor vem do banco.
$arr = range($inicio, $ultimo);
print_r($arr);
```

com o código acima me retorna um array de 1 ao número cadastrado no banco, nesse exemplo o 5.

seguindo o exemplo eu gostaria de colocar esse array num select html, de 1 á 5 no caso, eu tentei com for mas não obtive sucesso, alguém pode me dar uma luz? obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o comando `foreach` ou o `for` do seguinte modo:

```
<select>
<?php
    foreach ( $arr as $k => $v ) {
        echo "<option value=\"" . $k . "\">" . $v . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

A variável `$k` contém a chave que indexa o array, podendo ser tanto uma chave numérica quanto uma chave associativa (uma string); `$v` contém o valor do elemento na posição `$arr[$k]`.

Ou seja:

```
$arr[$k] === $v // true
```

Comment: Apenas um detalhe, neste caso o valor do value ($k) seria sempre -1 em relação ao exibido na opção ($v), uma vez que um parte de 0 e outro de 1.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Vinicius, muito obrigado mesmo, entendi bem o uso do foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Pode utilizar isso:

```
<?
$inicio = 1; 
$ultimo = 5; //esse valor vem do banco.

$arr = range($inicio, $ultimo);

print_r($arr);
?>
<select name="n">
<?
foreach($arr as $n){ 
?>

<option name = "n"value="<? echo $n ?>"><? echo $n ?></option>

<? 
} 
?>
</select>
```

Isso ira exibir um SELECT em HTML, com as opções devinidas em $n que é o mesmo de $arr.

Para cada $n irá exibir um OPTION dentro de um SELECT.

Comment: Também funcionou Inkeliz, muito obrigado.